# Don't invite people when moving their messages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, chat

Every time we move people's messages to some recycle bin/trash can room, they're invited to this room, thus leading to sarcastic comments such as [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9056608#9056608).

Should these invitations be disabled? I haven't seen any useful situation for those invitations when moving a message.

If you think there are useful cases, could there be some special rooms where people are not invited? Like "Recycle bin" or "Trash can".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Trash can" / "Recycle bin" system is just a (currently tolerated) abuse of the message migration functionality. It certainly is not a use case that we will support by special-casing such rooms.

If room owners want to go this way because they don't like not having deletion powers, they'll have to live with the fact that message owners are notified of the "pseudo-deletion".

Answer (score 6):

There is a use-case for invitations, such as when a user confuses Java and JavaScript (AGAIN!).  I think that a dedicated `trash bin` room should be created that doesn't invite people when messages are moved there.