# Reconsider not inviting people into chat rooms when their messages are moved, or make it optional

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, moderator-tools, room-owner

In 2013, there was a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177899/dont-invite-people-when-moving-their-messages) asking to disable the chat system's behavior to invite people into rooms when their messages are moved. That request was declined for the following reason:

> The "Trash can" / "Recycle bin" system is just a (currently tolerated) abuse of the message migration functionality. It certainly is not a use case that we will support by special-casing such rooms.

However, as of now, this is *not* considered an abuse of the move messages tool, but rather the **primary use case** of the tool. The [chat moderation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271269/377214) mentions it as the *sole* use case:

> If unsuitable messages are being posted, then you have the ability to move the messages to the trash can. A “trash” (or “bin”) is just a room created for the sole purpose of holding unwanted messages.

(It's worth noting that the text in question was written by a CM at the time, which means that it's considered official and thus **not** merely a "currently tolerated abuse".)

Prior to writing this request, I hadn't been aware of, and hadn't seen, any other use case of this tool, which would warrant sending an invitation to all users who sent messages that were moved. It's [confusing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=9056608#9056608) to new users, such that many official room websites [have an explicit disclaimer](https://socvr.org/faq#why-do-you-invite-me-to-the-cv-request-graveyard-room) in their list of rules.

Doing my research for this post, I found that the original reason why the tool was implemented was to allow conversations to continue in another room, in which sending invitations would be desired. I've personally never seen this being done on a wide scale; the majority of the feature's uses I've seen today are for trashing messages, not this. Also, sending invitations to *all* involved users isn't desirable: when a conversation is moved, I'd rather invite just the users who were recently participating in it, and not those who were initially involved but later left it. It's much better to keep invitations manual so that there are no unexpected surprises or annoyances.

There is a workaround, to have a moderator move messages to a private room, which doesn't send invitations since users can't be invited to private rooms, but that's not really desired since private rooms are intended solely for things involving PII and things unsuitable for the public record, and requires pinging a mod every time. Additionally, some rooms (e.g. SOCVR) routinely move messages that need to be cleaned but aren't necessarily unsuitable, and should be retained in a public archive.

In summary, can the decision to decline the earlier request please be reconsidered? While this may have been a minority use case at the time it was declined, it is the majority use case today, and the system should be coded around majority use cases rather than minority ones.

---

#### Update after answer

Per Mithical's answer, I see that the original use case of moving *currently ongoing* conversations to another room is still occasionally used. Their idea of having a checkbox option of whether to issue invitations or not seems like the best idea to me, but I think that's unlikely to be implemented due to the lack of chat development.

Given that, I still think that my original proposal to not issue invitations and have them handled manually if needed is the best option, if their proposal can't be implemented. As tripleee commented on their answer:

> There are already too many magical secrets which require you to know in detail how the system works, with very little documentation.

As an alternative proposal, though, I'd be open to issuing invitations *only if* messages are moved to a *public* room, not to a *gallery* room. There's already an exemption for chat invitations when messages are moved to private rooms; this is to have a similar exemption for gallery rooms. Pretty much all trashcan rooms across the network are set to gallery mode, to allow for a public archive but prevent users from talking in them. This would make it so that invitations are only issued when a conversation is moved and *being allowed to continue* in another room, *not* when a conversation is being *stopped* and the messages trashed. (**Update**: After further research, I found that users are actually [prevented from issuing invitations](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6787035#6787035) if the user to be invited doesn't have write access to the room. Since such invitations can't be issued manually, they shouldn't be being issued automatically either, and that they are being issued is a bug.)

Merely fixing the bug isn't ideal, because I may want to move a conversation to a publicly writable room, but still not issue invitations to anyone, if I'm moving a conversation that has since ended. Also, there's the issue of unexpected surprises that tripleee and I pointed out.

My preferred solutions are as followed, in order of decreasing preference:

1. Have a checkbox to indicate whether or not users should be invited
2. Not invite users at all, leaving that responsibility to a human
3. Fix the bug that automatically invites users even if messages are being moved into a gallery room where they don't have write access

Can we have the highest possible one of these, please?

Comment: The invitations to the destination room are useful in some cases and detrimental in other cases. I think a better feature request would be for an option in the move dialog to be able to disable notifications on a per-move basis. That would permit ROs/moderators to issue invitations to some users and not to others by performing two different moves. I would expect that it would be easier to implement such an option, rather than a way for ROs or moderators to designate specific rooms to not have invitations sent.

Comment: @Makyen This request asks to never have invitations sent. If invitations need to be sent, that can be done manually.

Comment: If you're moving a conversation involving multiple people, it's rather a pain in the rear to have to issue multiple separate invitations. As far as I know, there's no method to issue multiple invitations at the same time, other than by moving messages.

Comment: @Makyen Perhaps a better idea would be to not issue invitations if moving messages into a gallery chat room (as is already done for private rooms)? I'd upvote an answer requesting this.

Answer (score 17):

> I wasn't aware of, and hadn't seen, any other use case of this tool, which would warrant sending an invitation to all users who sent messages that were moved.

I've definitely used this tool in the past for its intended purpose - moving an active conversation to a different room where it would be more appropriate. Invitations were a good thing there.

I think that both use cases should be supported - both trashing messages and moving conversations. This could be accomplished by making it an *option* to send invitations when messages are moved. This could be, say, a checkbox in the move dialog that you can check or uncheck to send invitations for that particular move.

Comment: What do you think of the suggestion in my last comment on the question, to not send invites if the messages are moved to a gallery room?

Comment: I'm not Mithical, but I really would prefer an explicit option. There are already too many magical secrets which require you to know in detail how the system works, with very little documentation.

Comment: Personally, I agree, based on my time as an RPG.SE mod. It'd be nice to include those invites when moving a conversation to a more appropriate room, but those users shouldn't be invited when moving a chain of unwanted messages to some kind of "Trashcan" room. A checkbox for whether or not to invite the users when moving the messages would solve that issue.